# Git - erase commit history and restore previous instance of repo?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to completely erase commit history in Git, so that a commit cannot be seen, and restore the repository to the state it had at that point in time? If so, how can this be done, through the command line or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll back to a specific commit and delete all later commits as follows:

```
git reset --hard <HASH>
```

where `<HASH>` is the commit you want to roll back to. Obviously use it with care!

If you then want to push it up to a remote that already has later commits you need to push with the `--force` flag to delete the later commits.

Comment: This is usually the right answer to the question as asked, but it's worth mentioning that the rolled-back commits *are* still in the repository. They will remain there until they expire and are garbage-collected. That's normally just fine, but if there are sensitive data, it may not be—but it's *very* hard to purge such data; Git is deliberately "add-only" by default.

Comment: @torek Interesting, is there no easy way to manually delete commits? And how long do "deleted" commits typically take to expire?

Comment: @CraveableBanana: It's deliberately difficult because it's outside Git's design. (It's easier in Mercurial because it's inside the design.) Commits in Git are retained if and only if they are *reachable* in the commit DAG, by starting from some external reference such as a branch or tag name. However, every time you modify a reference, Git saves its previous value in a per-reference "reflog" entry. Reflog entries are time-stamped. The automatic `git gc` uses configuration values to choose when to expire them; the defaults are 30 days for some entries, 90 for the rest. [continued]

Comment: @CraveableBanana [cont] Once the reflog entries are gone, if the objects are unreachable, they can be pruned away by the garbage collector. Even then, though, there are several more things that may preserve them: date stamps (by default there's also a minimum 14 day grace period), and if packed, pack-file "keep" files (you can force Git to save particular pack files forever).